# new line issue with netcat

Tags: linux, unix

I am using below command to send some strings to udp listening server.

> echo "A 192.168.192.168" | nc -u 192.168.2.1 1234

but the server is getting trailing '\n' in echoed string.

I have tried below command too, but failed

> echo "A 192.168.192.168" | nc -uC 192.168.2.1 1234

How can I remove that trailing new line character ??
Do I have any special option in nc ??

Answer (score 15):

`echo` usually provides `-n` flag. This is not standard.

> *string*  A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' )  char‐
>                 acter, the results are implementation-defined.
>
> On  XSI-conformant  systems, if the first operand is -n, it shall be treated as a string, not an option.

---

I would suggest using `printf`

```
printf "A 192.168.192.168" | nc -u 192.168.2.1 1234
```

`printf` doesnt append a new line unless it is told to, and it's standard behavior.

Comment: I've never heard that the `-n` option on echo isn't standard, can you please elaborate on it? Every Linux/Unix system I have used over the years has had this.

Comment: see `man 1p echo` the POSIX man page for `echo`. Also the `echo` usually invoked is a shell builtin and not the actual executable under `/bin/echo`. Under _Bash_ for example, see what echo provides with `help echo`

Comment: Just tried `help echo` under `bash` on my Linux system and it gave `-n do not append a newline`. And realistically, how likely is anyone to come across `echo -n` *not* working?

Comment: Mind you, I'm not trying to say you are wrong or argue about a possible standard, but just given my experience over the years with different systems, perhaps this standard isn't quite that common yet?

Comment: with the `help echo` I wanted to show that the man page could specify very different things than what an `echo foo` command might actually produce. same goes with `printf`, most shells have a builtin `printf` which can differ from the actual executable `/usr/bin/printf`. The default is to execute the builtin command (equivalent to `builtin echo` `builin printf` ..), if one needs to invoked the executable, he needs to type the whole path, which is another reason why admins used to do that for every command in their scripts.

Comment: the fact that many people like to depend on _implementation-defined_ behavior doesnt make it good or correct, neither does the fact that it's rare (how many people use _Plan9_ ?) to find an `echo` where `-n` is handled as a plain string and not as a switch. The choice is yours to make. I just made a suggestion :)

Comment: I guess my point was that while it may not be standard, it is prevalent and therefore something that will work usually, so I think starting out with "it's not standard" while technically true is a bit misleading. In cases when it doesn't a different work-around can be found. I wasn't aware of the XSI-conformant systems definition, nor could I name any XSI-conformant system :) .. but I mostly come from a user perspective. I appreciate the new information. The goal is to help OP solve their problem and accomplish their task after all.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `printf` as an alternative

Comment: thnx for the ans. it was very helpful

Answer (score 9):

Try using

```
echo -n
```

so

```
echo -n "A 192.168.192.168" | nc -u 192.168.2.1 1234
```

[echo man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?echo) says:  `-n    do not output the trailing newline`