# Lost UDP packages with PHP socket_sendto

Tags: php, linux, sockets, udp

I have a PHP CMS system, that's sending a UDP package to switch off a device on the local network.

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
if (!$sock) {
    echo "COULD NOT CREATE SOCKET";
}
$result = socket_sendto($sock, "Ausgang1AUS", 11, 0, "192.168.20.49", 30303);
socket_close($sock);
if ($result) echo "UDP SENT ".$result." BYTES";
```

This has been working perfectly on our old (dedicated) linux server.

Now since switching to a new (virtual) linux server, these packages never reach their target.
I get no error in PHP (just my "UDP SENT 11 BYTES", but the packages just do not arrive anywhere in the local network.

It DOES work if I send the UDP to the server itself (using it's own IP).

It DOES work if I run this script on another machine in the local network.

It DOES work if I send UDP via netcat, e.g.
`echo "Ausgang1AUS" | nc -u 192.168.20.49 30303`. So it shouldn't be a general blocking problem.

Firewall and SELinux are both disabled on the machine.

Does anyone have an idea whats happening? Could it be some PHP setting or some user privilege? Is there any tool I could use to find out whats's happening to the UDP package?

I'm pretty lost at the moment...

**Edit:**
Seems to have nothing to do with php socket_sendto in the end, but connect to the LENGTH of the data sent. So @stark was right, using echo (thus introducing a newline) changed the length from 11 bytes to 12 bytes, and suddenly packages do arrive.

I posted a new question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1737472/udp-packages-with-datalength-12bytes-not-sent)

Comment: UDP packets are dropped when a network buffer is full somewhere in the path. TCP has congestion control to avoid this.

Comment: You might need to sniff packets with something like wire shark

Comment: @stark: But if it's a full network buffer, sending via netcat shouldn't work as well, right?

Comment: echo adds a newline, so they are not sending the same bytes.

Comment: @stark: I know... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273999/new-line-issue-with-netcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this virtual Linux server running on a Windows VM? There was a recent Windows update that introduced a bug in hypervisor which is causing UDP packets under 12 bytes to fail checksum validation.

There's a Github issues here where other users are reporting the same issue on WSL2.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8610

You can see there's a workaround posted in that thread that might help in your situation, at least until Microsoft manage to fix the issue:
`ethtool -K eth0 tx off`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan, you saved my month!!!